# Arrays value being treated differently than manual input

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have this function:

```
public function getReward($formattedArray, $key){
    $id = $formattedArray[$key][0];
    //dd($id); //Returns 1
    $reward = Item::find($id); 
    return $reward;
}
```

The issue part is:

```
$reward = Item::find($id);
```

I have dd() the id variable and it returns the expected value of 1, which then is used in the static find function at the end. I then receive errors using this function "Trying to get property of non-object".

I then do this:

```
$reward = Item::find($id); //Changed to...
$reward = Item::find(1);
```

The only difference being that I manually input the integer 1 into the static find function. The code works perfectly without errors and I'm able to access the object returned.

Working Example:

```
$reward = Item::find(1); 
return $reward;
```

Working Example:

```
$reward = Item::find("1"); 
return $reward;
```

Non-working Example:

```
$reward = Item::find($formattedArray[$key][0]); 
return $reward;
```

I have also tried casting to an integer like so:

```
$id = $formattedArray[$key][0];
    $idInt = (int) $id;
    $reward = Item::find($idInt);
    return $reward;
```

Comment: Where's your static function find code? `1` isn't an object (primitive data type), so I have a feeling it's not related to the problem with the input, also what values are your array?

Comment: Maybe the problem inside Item::find(). but before, try this: $id=1; an then try to call the Item::find($id). If you still face the problem, then give us the code of Item::find()

Comment: find() is a function from within Eloquent used on Laravel framework. It takes an integer as an ID and pulls the record from a database using the ID. Entering 1 into find() manually is fine. But when I'm getting the integer 1 from my multidimensional array, it isnt fine. hope that makes sense

Comment: @DarrylChapman did you try $id=1? try var_dump($formattedArray[$key][0]) to know the type of the value that you get

Comment: `var_dump($id)`, then. see exactly what that value is. maybe it's `1<br />` or something

Comment: $id=1 works.  var_dump returns  string(1) "1"

Answer (score 0):

I think $id , you are getting is not object type. 
To confirm that use var_dump(), because your Item::find() function trying to access some field that is not accessible.